# BindableProperty (List<>) in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

my problem is the following:
I have my `ContentPage` which has a `ResourceDictionary` with some
`DataTemplate`s. One of the templates takes the `Horse` Object (which holds the `List<Weight>`'s).
I display several stats of that object but when I want to pass variables from the `Horse` Object to another view such as the following:

```
<graph:LineGraph x:Name="displayWeight" WeightOfHorse="{Binding Weight}"/>
```

Code Behind `WeightOfHorse`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty WeightOfHorseProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(WeightOfHorse),
    typeof(IList<Weight>),
    typeof(LineGraph),
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

public IList<Weight> WeightOfHorse
{
    get => (IList<Weight>)GetValue(WeightOfHorseProperty);
    set => SetValue(WeightOfHorseProperty, value);
}
```

I just don't manage to pass the values, I know that they are available because I can display them in a simple `Collectionview`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this works. It seems that you need to assign the property by the changing event.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty WeightOfHorseProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
nameof(WeightOfHorse),
typeof(IEnumerable<Weight>),
typeof(LineGraph),
defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);

public IEnumerable<Weight> WeightOfHorse
{
get => (IEnumerable<Weight>)GetValue(WeightOfHorseProperty);
set => SetValue(WeightOfHorseProperty, value);
}

static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
var control = (LineGraph)bindable;
control.WeightOfHorse = (List<Weight>)newValue;
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, glad have found the solution! Rmember to mark it when you have time, it will be helpful for other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change IList to ObservableCollection.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, what does it matter? Maybe I was unclear, the property was never set. So it seems that it never passes the values.